# Eclipse Luna F6 doesn't step over

Tags: eclipse, debugging

Strange, I have a Java application in Eclipse Luna and when debugging it and I'm trying to use F6 it doesn't "step over", but instead it "steps into".

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it lack any detail making it possible to answer.

Comment: Well did you double-check your keybindings?

Answer (score 0):

I was trying to build a Java applicaton in Eclipse Luna. It was a database application from 
[here](http://www.programcreek.com/2012/12/how-to-make-a-web-crawler-using-java/).

With two source files (DB.java):

```
`import java.sql.Connection;
import java.sql.DriverManager;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;

public class DB {

public Connection conn = null;

public DB() {
    try {
        Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
        String url = "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/Crawler";
        conn = DriverManager.getConnection(url, "root", "admin213");
        System.out.println("conn built");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}

public ResultSet runSql(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    return sta.executeQuery(sql);
}

public boolean runSql2(String sql) throws SQLException {
    Statement sta = conn.createStatement();
    return sta.execute(sql);
}

@Override
protected void finalize() throws Throwable {
    if (conn != null || !conn.isClosed()) {
        conn.close();
    }
}
}`
```

and Main.java:

```
`import java.io.IOException;
import java.sql.PreparedStatement;
import java.sql.ResultSet;
import java.sql.SQLException;
import java.sql.Statement;
import org.jsoup.Jsoup;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Document;
import org.jsoup.nodes.Element;
import org.jsoup.select.Elements;


public class Main {
    public static DB db = new DB();

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SQLException, IOException {
        db.runSql2("TRUNCATE Record;");
        processPage("http://www.mit.edu");
    }

    public static void processPage(String URL) throws SQLException, IOException{
        //check if the given URL is already in database
        String sql = "select * from Record where URL = '"+URL+"'";
        ResultSet rs = db.runSql(sql);
        if(rs.next()){

        }else{
            //store the URL to database to avoid parsing again
            sql = "INSERT INTO  `Crawler`.`Record` " + "(`URL`) VALUES " + "(?);";
            PreparedStatement stmt = db.conn.prepareStatement(sql,
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
            stmt.setString(1, URL);
            stmt.execute();

            //get useful information
            Document doc = Jsoup.connect("http://www.mit.edu/").get();

            if(doc.text().contains("research")){
                System.out.println(URL);
            }

            //get all links and recursively call the processPage method
            Elements questions = doc.select("a[href]");
            for(Element link: questions){
                if(link.attr("href").contains("mit.edu"))
                processPage(link.attr("abs:href"));
            }
        }
    }
}`
```

I forgot to include the mysql-connector-java-5.1.16-bin.jar into the buildpath.
This resulted in an exception occuring in the initialization that occurs in the DB()
initializer code. At least this is my assumption that the behaviour of Eclipse was
irritated (maybe it's a feature?) and the step over didn't work right.